# Fake energy saver inductive loads

Tags: capacitor, inductive, power-meter

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFKdV4v_Wlk) on YouTube, it covered fake energy saving devices.

I have seen many of these fake devices and they all seem to use a capacitor. My question is why would they bother? The person in the video explains that the capacitor would change the inductive loads, however normal household electric meters do not measure this.

Perhaps there are still countries which do pay for inductive loads where this device could be used? Otherwise, why would the scammers waste money on a capacitor and changing the inductive load...?

P.S I know nothing about electricity so please keep this at an easy level!

Comment: It’s just a plastic cap and offers no more than 25 VARs of passive PFC at 250V. Fake

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why would they bother?

If the device contained nothing it would obviously be fraud, so they put in an inexpensive part. It is still fraud, but only informed people will know.

Answer (score 1):

The best frauds are based on an element of truth.

Domestic meters generally measure watts. The householder only gets charged for actual power, not reactive power, so these 'cap in a plug' devices do not save money.

However, power factor correction for electricity users at an industrial scale is a thing. A rolling mill might run 100MW of motors. If these run at a low inductive power factor, the feeders leading to the factory will be taking more current than if they were running at unity power factor. The actual dissipation loss that this causes through \$I^2R\$ loss in the lines, plus the need for heavier cables to supply excess current, is a real cost to the electricity supplier. Consequently, they 'encourage' big users to correct their loads for power factor, by charging them for VAr as well as watts. There is a market in large capacitor banks for installation at factories for this purpose.

If challenged, the 'cap in a plug' scammers can point to real life examples of inductive power factor correction, but fudge the significance of any inductive correction.